# npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-browser-support'

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to install the latest mfpdev-cli version (8.0.2016062816) but I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mfpdev-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-browser-support
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-browser-support'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-browser-support'
npm ERR! enoent
This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! anoint
```

Checking the repository, I was not able to find the mdo-* modules, this is the problem.

I also tried to install it through the .tar.gz file, but same error.

Is there a "workaround" on this issue?

Comment: What is your OS and Version?

Comment: A new fixed version has been uploaded to npm. use the following to update: "npm install -g mfpdev-cli".

Answer (score 1):

Try :

sudo npm install -g mfpdev-cli@8.0.2016062416 --no-optional

Looks like newer builds have an issue.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will test this version with Bluemix.

Comment: A fixed version will be released soon.

Comment: A new fixed version has been uploaded to npm. use the following to update: "npm install -g mfpdev-cli".

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the install with "sudo".

`sudo npm install -g mfpdev-cli`